# Truffle Chai Assertion Error with Truffle Unit Cases

Tags: solidity, truffle, javascript, test, chai

Problem: facing an issue with the below Truffle test case while trying to Implement the ERC20 token in my contract.

```
contract("Token Test", async(accounts) => {

const[deployerAccount, recipient, anotherAccount] = accounts;

it("All tokens should be in deployer's account", async() => {
    let instance = await Token.deployed();
    let totalSupply = await instance.totalSupply();
    // let balance = await instance.balanceOf(accounts[0]);
    // assert.equal(balance.valueOf(), totalSupply.valueOf(), "The Balance Was not same");

    expect(instance.balanceOf(deployerAccount)).to.eventually.be.a.bignumber.equal(totalSupply);
});

it("Is possible to send tokens between accounts", async() => {
    const sendToken = 1;
    let instance = await Token.deployed();
    let totalSupply = await instance.totalSupply();
    expect(instance.balanceOf(deployerAccount)).to.eventually.be.a.bignumber.equal(totalSupply);
    expect(instance.transfer(recipient, sendToken)).to.eventually.be.fulfilled;
    expect(instance.balanceOf(deployerAccount)).to.eventually.be.a.bignumber.equal(totalSupply.sub(new BN(sendToken)));
    expect(instance.balanceOf(recipient)).to.eventually.be.a.bignumber.equal(new BN(sendToken));
}); 

it("Should not be able to send more token than available with owner", async() => {
    let instance = await Token.deployed();
    let balanceOfDeployer = await instance.balanceOf(deployerAccount);
    console.log(balanceOfDeployer+ " : " + await instance.balanceOf(deployerAccount));
    // expect(instance.transfer(recipient, new BN(balanceOfDeployer+3))).to.eventually.be.rejected;

    expect(instance.balanceOf(deployerAccount)).to.eventually.be.a.bignumber.equal(balanceOfDeployer);
});

});
```

Description: When I am trying to execute test cases 2 and 3 at the same time it is failing with the below error:

```
"before all" hook: prepare suite for "Should not be able to send more token than available with owner":

  Uncaught AssertionError: expected '1000000000' to equal '999999999'
  + expected - actual

  -1000000000
  +999999999
  
  at /project_dir/node_modules/chai-as-promised/lib/chai-as-promised.js:302:22
  at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)



UnhandledRejections detected
Promise {
  <rejected> AssertionError: expected '1000000000' to equal '999999999'
      at /project_dir/node_modules/chai-as-promised/lib/chai-as-promised.js:302:22
      at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5) {
    showDiff: true,
    actual: '1000000000',
    expected: '999999999',
    operator: 'strictEqual',
    uncaught: true
  }
```

However when I try to execute both test cases independently (commenting test case 2 keeping 3, and vice-versa). They work fine and are completed without any error.

Need help understanding what am I missing here and how to fix it.

Things I have tried:
Initially, I thought that this is might be happening due to state change in the variable in test case 2. So I moved test case 3 to a new contract(). But I was still facing the same issue. However, this should not be happening as contract() provides a clean room environment before executing every contract test.

P.S.: I am initiating the value of totalSupply to 1000000000 in the constructor of Contract.

Answer (score 1):

Your `.to.` should be replaced with `.should.` to support the `.eventually.` interface.

Explained in [Chai docs](https://www.chaijs.com/plugins/chai-as-promised/), you

> The most powerful extension provided by Chai as Promised is the eventually property. With it, you can transform any existing Chai assertion into one that acts on a promise:

```
return promise.should.be.fulfilled;
return promise.should.eventually.deep.equal("foo");
return promise.should.become("foo"); // same as `.eventually.deep.equal`
return promise.should.be.rejected;
return promise.should.be.rejectedWith(Error); // other variants of Chai's `throw` assertion work too.
```

But you don't need to use chai-as-promised because the comparison should be a promise too, even if you change `to` to `should` you'll still get an error `TypeError: <BN: 3b9aca00> is not a thenable`.

So simple drop `.eventually` and add `await` on the expect param, so this

```
expect(instance.balanceOf(deployerAccount)).should.eventually.be.a.bignumber.equal(totalSupply);
```

will transform to

```
expect(await instance.balanceOf(deployerAccount)).to.be.a.bignumber.equal(totalSupply);
```

and it will work properly.

Full working tests -

```
    it("All tokens should be in deployer's account", async () => {
        let instance = await Token.deployed();
        let totalSupply = await instance.totalSupply();
        // let balance = await instance.balanceOf(accounts[0]);
        // assert.equal(balance.valueOf(), totalSupply.valueOf(), "The Balance Was not same");

        expect(await instance.balanceOf(deployerAccount)).to.be.a.bignumber.equal(totalSupply);
    });

    it("Is possible to send tokens between accounts", async () => {
        const sendToken = 1;
        let instance = await Token.deployed();
        let totalSupply = await instance.totalSupply();
        expect(await instance.balanceOf(deployerAccount)).to.be.a.bignumber.equal(totalSupply);
        await instance.transfer(recipient, sendToken);
        expect(await instance.balanceOf(deployerAccount)).to.be.a.bignumber.equal(totalSupply.sub(new BN(sendToken)));
        expect(await instance.balanceOf(recipient)).to.be.a.bignumber.equal(new BN(sendToken));
    });

    it("Should not be able to send more token than available with owner", async () => {
        let instance = await Token.deployed();
        let balanceOfDeployer = await instance.balanceOf(deployerAccount);
        console.log(balanceOfDeployer + " : " + await instance.balanceOf(deployerAccount));

        expect(await instance.balanceOf(deployerAccount)).to.be.a.bignumber.equal(balanceOfDeployer);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this might be a concurrency issue. Have you tried placing `await` before each and every possibly async call? Example:

```js
await expect(instance.balanceOf(deployerAccount)).to.eventually.be.a.bignumber.equal(totalSupply);
```

Also, I would try replacing:

```js
expect(instance.transfer(recipient, sendToken)).to.eventually.be.fulfilled;
```

with:

```js
await instance.transfer(recipient, sendToken);
```